# How to view toggle / view multiple monitors using VNC?

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer

Trying to remotely view and control user's PCs, nowadays everyone has multiple screens which I need to see. I've googled around tightvnc, ultravnc and tigervnc but none of these seem to work. I can only ever just see 1 screen someone has. I was reading about mirror drivers and I tried to install it for tightvnc but didn't seem to do anything.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If the computer you're logging into has 2 monitors then just log into the computer with Tight VNC two times and have the scroller bar for each VNC window positioned how you prefer.

Comment: This is jank but actually not a half bad idea

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I found on the subject is to switch to "Scale to window size" from options -> display. It shrinks the image though as this option was meant to fit everything in a single monitor.